# how to fix Network on Main Thread Exception issue in google play console

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, networking, console

In my kotlin project, google play console one error in Stability is - "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". Please anyone help me to fix this issue. I have attached the screenshot of this issue and also i have added the signupactivity code i have used in my kotlin project. [image]

class SignUpActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NetworkDialog.NetworkListener, GetResult.MyListener {

```
private lateinit var signUpViewModel: SignUpViewModel
private lateinit var locationViewModel: LocationViewModel
private var latitude: Double? = null
private var longitude: Double? = null
private var countryName: String? = null
private var countryCode: String? = null
private var state: String? = null
private var city: String? = null
private var nameUser: String? = null
private var email: String? = null
private var year: String? = null
private var month: String? = null
private var passwordUser: String? = null
private var isGPSEnabled = false
private lateinit var locationViewModelLatLong: Locationviewmodell
private  lateinit var  geoCoder: Geocoder 


private val viewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels {
    object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
            MainViewModel(
                CoLocation.from(this@SignUpActivity),
                CoGeocoder.from(this@SignUpActivity)
            ) as T
    }
}

companion object {
    const val requestShowSettings = 123       
} 

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
    date.listen()
    DPref.init(this@SignUpActivity)
    signUpViewModel =    ViewModelProviders.of(this@SignUpActivity).get(SignUpViewModel::class.java)
    locationViewModel =   ViewModelProviders.of(this@SignUpActivity).get(LocationViewModel::class.java)
    locationViewModelLatLong = ViewModelProviders.of(this@SignUpActivity).get(Locationviewmodell::class.java)
    GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(object : GpsUtils.OnGpsListener {
        override fun gpsStatus(isGPSEnable: Boolean) {
            this@SignUpActivity.isGPSEnabled = isGPSEnable
        }
    })


    signInButton.setOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }
    date.minDate = dateMinMax(-99)
    date.maxDate = dateMinMax(-18)

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
        try {
            if (NetworkUtils.checkConnection()) {
                invokeLocationAction()
                isRegister()
              
            } else {
                val networkDialog = NetworkDialog()
                networkDialog.showDialog(this@SignUpActivity)
                networkDialog.setNetworkListener(this@SignUpActivity)
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    signUpViewModel.getUserSignUpData().observe(this) {
        it.apply {
            nameUser = userName
            email = userEmail
            year = userYear
            month = userMonth
            passwordUser = userPassword
        }
    }

    locationViewModel.getUserSignUpLocationData().observe(this) {
        it.apply {
            latitude = userLatitude
            longitude = userLongitude
            countryName = userCountryName
            countryCode = userCountryCode
            state = userState
            city = userCity
        }
    }

}


inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> ViewModelProvider.Factory)? = null,
): Lazy<VM> {
    val factoryPromise = factoryProducer ?: {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }
    return ViewModelLazy(VM::class, { viewModelStore }, factoryPromise)
}



@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == GPS_REQUEST) {
            isGPSEnabled = true
            invokeLocationAction()
        }
    }
}

private fun invokeLocationAction() {
    when {
        !isGPSEnabled ->
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUpActivity, "Please enable your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        isPermissionsGranted() -> startLocationUpdate()
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() ->
            showSettingsDialog()
        else -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
            LOCATION_REQUEST
        )
    }
}

private fun startLocationUpdate() {

    locationViewModelLatLong.getLocationData().observe(this, Observer {


        val la = it.latitude
        val lo = it.longitude
        Log.d("SignUpActivity", "getLocationData() it.userLatitude$la")
        Log.d("SignUpActivity", "getLocationData() it.userLatitude$lo")
        getLocation(la,lo)

    })
}

private fun isPermissionsGranted() = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

private fun shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    when (requestCode) {
        LOCATION_REQUEST -> {
            invokeLocationAction()
        }
    }
}


private fun getLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double){
    try {
        geoCoder = Geocoder(this@SignUpActivity, Locale.ENGLISH)
        val addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)


        val countryName = addresses?.get(0)?.countryName
        val countryCode = addresses?.get(0)?.countryCode
        val state = addresses?.get(0)?.adminArea
        val city = addresses?.get(0)?.locality

        val locationData = LocationModelClass(
            userLatitude = latitude,
            userLongitude = longitude,
            userCountryName = countryName,
            userCountryCode = countryCode,
            userState = state,
            userCity = city
        )
        locationViewModel.setUserSignUpLocationData(locationModelClass = locationData)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

}

const val LOCATION_REQUEST = 100
const val GPS_REQUEST = 101

[image]

view model codes:

```
class Locationviewmodell (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val locationData = LocationLiveData(application)

fun getLocationData() = locationData
```

}

class LocationViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
private val userLocationData: MutableLiveData<LocationModelClass> =
    MutableLiveData<LocationModelClass>()

fun setUserSignUpLocationData(locationModelClass: LocationModelClass) {
    userLocationData.value = locationModelClass
}

fun getUserSignUpLocationData(): MutableLiveData<LocationModelClass> {
    return userLocationData
}
```

}

```
class GpsUtils(private val context: Context) {

private val settingsClient: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context)
private val locationSettingsRequest: LocationSettingsRequest?
private val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

init {
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(LocationLiveData.locationRequest)
    locationSettingsRequest = builder.build()
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true)
}

fun turnGPSOn(OnGpsListener: OnGpsListener?) {

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        OnGpsListener?.gpsStatus(true)
    } else {
        settingsClient
            .checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(context as Activity) {
                //  GPS is already enable, callback GPS status through listener
                OnGpsListener?.gpsStatus(true)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(context) { e ->
                when ((e as ApiException).statusCode) {
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->

                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                            // result in onActivityResult().
                            val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
                            rae.startResolutionForResult(context, GPS_REQUEST)
                        } catch (sie: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                          
                        }

                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        val errorMessage =
                            "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " + "fixed here. Fix in Settings."
                        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage)

                        Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

interface OnGpsListener {
    fun gpsStatus(isGPSEnable: Boolean)
}
```

}

Comment: Those are coming from instrumented tests, not actual users.

Comment: Yes, but i need to clear all console warnings... any solution available for this one?